# Django cascade delete doesn't remove pk of referenced model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.9

In Django 1.9 I have related objects defined in **models.py** as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Note(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

When I delete a `Course`, I expect all related `Note` s to delete via the default cascade behaviour. What I get is the following behaviour:

```
>>> from test1.models import Course, Note

#First, create a Course and associated Note
>>> c1 = Course()
>>> c1.save()
>>> n1 = Note(course=c1)
>>> n1.save()
>>> c1.pk
4
>>> n1.pk
4

#Next, delete the Course, and see if Note deletes too
>>> c1.delete()
(2, {'test1.Course': 1, 'test1.Note': 1})
>>> c1.pk
>>> n1.pk
1    #pk remains
>>> Note.objects.get(pk=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...    test1.models.DoesNotExist: Note matching query does not exist.

#Finally, try deleting the Note manually
>>> n1.delete()
(0, {'test1.Note': 0})
>>> n1.pk
>>> #finally the pk is gone!
```

It seems that the database is correctly updated but only the Course object is updated locally, while the Note object is not (i.e. keeps its pk).

*Why is this, and how can I get Note to also delete pk so that it's in sync with the db?*

**Extra info**: My reason for needing this behaviour is that I have used statements like `if note.pk:` elsewhere to check if a given `Note` is already saved in the database. Unfortunately, this style of cascade delete renders these statements useless because pk's exist even when db entries have been deleted.

Comment: Please can you post a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently `Note` has a foreign key to some non-existent model `A`. Also in the sample code you're not actually saving the created objects, so the subsequent code (to delete) would fail.

Comment: @solarissmoke Fixed! I had originally tried to get rid of some complexities of my real project but I screwed it up. The revised code has been tested as is and behaves as shown

Comment: Did you try on_delete attribute? @ZG101

Comment: @EliasMP The default is `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, which is what I want, so I haven't changed it. It is deleting the related Note in the database as expected, but not updating the pk to None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Once Django has fetched something from the database (`n1` in this case) it isn't going to know about changes to it until you fetch it again (either with `Note.objects.get(pk=4)` or `n1.refresh_from_db()`.

When you call `c1.delete()`, Django deletes that row from the database and clears the `pk` on the object. It also deletes all related objects *in the database* that are set to cascade. However it has no way of knowing what other already-instantiated objects are referencing that object - how could it?

Here is a simpler example of the same behaviour, without foreign keys:

```
# Fetch a Course
>>> c1 = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
# Fetch the same course again, but save it to a different variable
>>> c2 = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Note that you now have two instances of the same row in the database. Now:

```
# Delete c1
>>> c1.delete()

# c2 Hasn't changed... how could it? That would be magical.
>>> c2.pk
1

# but if you refresh c2 from the database... it isn't there
>>> c2.refresh_from_db()
DoesNotExist: Course matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Thanks and nice example! I was previously checking for saved objects via `if c2.pk:` and it was failing. I think I'll have to catch the `DoesNotExist` error and deal with it like that